# Inconsistent commit behavior between T-SQL transaction and SqlTransaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I am trying to figure out the reason for inconsistent behavior between the two *experiments* I run in the example code below. The first experiment uses T-SQL `BEGIN TRAN ... COMMIT TRAN` statements while the second one uses `SqlTransaction`. Otherwise, both perform similar actions:

1. Create a table in the database.
2. Start a transaction.
3. Perform a query that aquires an exclusive lock on the table.
4. Spawn a background task and perform a read-only query on the table in a dedicated connection.
   *Because the table is exclusively locked by a different connection, this query will have to wait until locks have been released.*
5. While iterating over a data reader in the original transaction, throw an exception.
6. Wait for and display the result of a background task.

```
using System;
// TODO: Add package reference to System.Data.SqlClient
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

await Logic.ExperimentAsync(useBackendTransaction: false);
await Logic.ExperimentAsync(useBackendTransaction: true);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

static class Logic
{
    // TODO: initialize a valid connection string
    public const string ConnectionString = "";

    static readonly string RecreateTable = @"
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [TempTable];
CREATE TABLE [TempTable] ([Value] int);";

    static readonly string TruncateInsertAndSelect = @"
---- BEGIN TRAN MssqlTransaction;

TRUNCATE TABLE [TempTable];

INSERT INTO [TempTable]([Value])
VALUES      (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);


WITH
  L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS D(c)), -- 2^1
  L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),       -- 2^2
  L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),       -- 2^4
  L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),       -- 2^8
  L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),       -- 2^16
  L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),       -- 2^32
  Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS k FROM L5)

SELECT k AS id
FROM Nums
WHERE k <= 100000000;

---- COMMIT TRAN MssqlTransaction;";

    static readonly string Select = @"
SELECT TOP 1 SUM([Value]) FROM [TempTable];";

    public static async Task ExperimentAsync(bool useBackendTransaction)
    {
        await using var aConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        await aConn.OpenAsync();

        // Recreate table
        await using var aCmd = aConn.CreateCommand();
        aCmd.CommandText = RecreateTable;
        await aCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

        // Add data and select
        aCmd.CommandText = useBackendTransaction
            ? TruncateInsertAndSelect
            : TruncateInsertAndSelect.Replace("---- ", String.Empty);
        aCmd.Transaction = useBackendTransaction
            ? aConn.BeginTransaction("BackendTransaction")
            : null;

        bool aErrors = false;
        Task<string> aSecondarySelectTask = null;
        try
        {
            await using var aRdr = await aCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            // In `useBackendTransaction = false' mode, SQL Profiler logs
            // a successfull commit of "MssqlTransaction" at this point.

            aSecondarySelectTask = SecondarySelectAsync();

            while (await aRdr.ReadAsync())
                throw new Exception();  // Throw on purpose when reader is active
        }
        catch
            { aErrors = true; }
        
        if (aCmd.Transaction != null)
        {
            if (!aErrors)
                await aCmd.Transaction.CommitAsync();
            else
                await aCmd.Transaction.RollbackAsync();
        }

        var aPrefix = useBackendTransaction
            ? "Using backend transactions"
            : "  Using MSSQL transactions";
        Console.WriteLine($"{aPrefix}: {await aSecondarySelectTask}");
    }

    private static async Task<string> SecondarySelectAsync()
    {
        var aConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        await aConn.OpenAsync();

        await using var aCmd = aConn.CreateCommand();
        aCmd.CommandText = Select;

        return await aCmd.ExecuteScalarAsync(CancellationToken.None) is int aRet
            ? aRet.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            : "(null)";
    }
}
```

Strangely though, the two experiments display different results:

```
  Using MSSQL transactions: 45
Using backend transactions: (null)
```

From my (fruitless) investigations,  T-SQL transaction somehow gets committed *before* a corresponding data reader appears in scope. On the other hand, a `SqlTransaction` will only commit *after* the data reader closes.

What's causing such inconsistent behavior? Maybe I'm doing something wrong? A link to the documentation (or source code, if applicable) would be greatly appreciated in the answer.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Modes of Transactions in SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/modes-of-transactions-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question a few days ago?

Comment: One version commits, but the other rolls back. What exactly is the question, why should this not happen? If you threw an exception *within* the SQL batch, that would be a different matter (and probably only if you have `SET XACT_ABORT ON` which you should always have)

Comment: @Charlieface: I did. Because it had two closure votes, I decided to ask a clearer question.
"One version commits, but the other rolls back. What exactly is the question ... ?" Yes, that part of the question. Another part is: how to write code where both approaches behave consistently.

Comment: They do behave consistently. They are doing exactly what you are asking. One is being committed because that's what you asked it to do in the SQL batch, one is being rolled back from the client side. They are simply doing different things. To replicate the automatic rollback in the bare SQL batch, use `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` at the top, and in the middle use `THROW 50001, 'Some error', 1;`

Comment: Reposting a question (especially to avoid closure) is against the rules though, @Kerido . If you want to improve a question, use the edit feature.

Comment: @Larnu: Sorry if I'm acting suspiciously. I actually deleted the question myself and tried to put emphasis differently: the original question had emphasis on performance, the current on business logic.

Comment: I didn't see the previous question, but there's nothing wrong with this question.  And since very few people monitor the reopen queues, deleting a question and re-posting a better one the only practical alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Disposing a SqlDataReader does not cancel the batch.

When you Dispose your SqlDataReader the outstanding rows are fetched and the batch is allowed to complete normally, running COMMIT TRAN, unblocking the other session and allowing it to read all the rows.

If you Cancel() the command before the full resultset has been buffered to send to the client, then you'll be left with an open transaction on that connection, and that connection that will block the other session.  However smallish resultsets are buffered to the client's output buffer and the batch proceeds to the next statement before the client has fetched the rows.  So you would need a larger resultset to see this happen.

SqlDataReader.Dispose calls SqlDataReader.Close and

> The Close method populates the values for output parameters, return
> values and RecordsAffected on the SqlDataReader by **consuming any
> pending results**

[SqlDataReader.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close?view=sqlclient-dotnet-4.1#remarks)

Comment: I updated the code so that a huge resultset is output by the `SELECT` statement. Currently, 100 million rows are SELECTed which should be enough not to fit in the buffer. However, I do get the same behavior and different console output.

Comment: @Kerido It's the behaviour of `SqlDataReader`, when you dispose it, it will send an `Attention` signal, which may or may not complete the batch, it's not guaranteed.

Comment: SqlDataReader.Close doesn't send an Attention.  It consumes the pending results and allows the batch to continue.  Only SqlCommand.Cancel sends an Attention.